# JVM args at cell level in IBM Websphere Application Server

Tags: websphere, jvm-arguments

Is there any way to set a JVM args like -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true at cell level in order to apply/pass all JVM at cell  in Websphere Application Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, through wsadmin scripting.  There's a script here: 
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/Dougclectica/entry/wasadmin_script_to_set_websphere_jvm_properties7?lang=en

Answer (score 0):

There's no direct way to specify JVM arguments at cell level that will apply to the JVMs of all application servers and cluster members in a cell configuration.  Indirectly, you can configure a WebSphere variable in the cell scope (e.g. name=JVM_ARG_1, value=-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true), and then specify the variable as a generic JVM argument in the Java Virtual Machine configuration of every AppServer or Cluster member in the cell (e.g. "${JVM_ARG_1}"). When starting an AppServer or Cluster, WebSphere Application Server will add the variable's value to the java command that launches the server JVM(s). If this is a requirement of your cell administration, you might create a server template and specify the cell-scoped WebSphere variable as a generic JVM argument in the template's Java Virtual Machine configuration. Then, your cell-scoped "JVM argument" will apply to every server created from the template.